# How do I pronounce the word "lounge"?

Tags: pronunciation

How do I pronounce the word "lounge"?

The problem is on Google I found many links which play audio for pronunciation. 
 Unfortunately I am not having an audio device so I cannot hear anything.

Comment: Surely all we should do is point you to [a dictionary](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/lounge?q=lounge)? /laʊn(d)ʒ/

Comment: It's easy to presuppose that every English language learner should be familiar with the IPA sound chart, but it's simply not true. And then I'm still dubious as to how effective the chart is without actually hearing the word itself. The IPA system is a great aid when it is combined with audio, ironically enough, or if you have a competent speaker who can demonstrate how these sounds are formed by the lips, the tongue, the teeth, and different facial muscles. I'd be curious to know if you can master the pronunciation of a language without ever hearing it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Lounge* is pronounced like /laʊndʒ/ and rhymes with *scrounge*.

The "lou-" bit rhymes with the "rou-" of *round* and "bou-" of *bounce*.

The "-nge" bit is like that in *syringe* and *cringe*.

Answer (score 3):

### laʊndʒ

this is the phonetic transcription as given by Oxford Advanced Learners Dictionary also commonly referred to as OALD

This is their page which describes how the [symbols are pronounced](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/pronunciation.html). It's well worth the effort learning the phonetic symbols, as most good dictionaries will use the International Phonetic Alphabet system, and write the pronunciation of words next to every entry. You can see the latest [IPA chart](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Phonetic_Alphabet#IPA_chart) on Wikipedia.

L as in **l***eg*

OU as in *n***ow**

N as in **n***ow*

GE as in **j***am*

Answer (score 1):

lounge (/laʊndʒ/)

l + oun (as in sound) + dʒ  (an in **j**ust, or ba**dg**er, fu**dg**e)

rhymes with scrounge; ou sound as in bouncer, counter, fountain, hour, mountain

Comment: Where did you get that use of /j/ from?

Comment: It's just that it's not IPA, which is what is customarily used here between //. IPA's /j/ is the sound normally associated with the letter ***y***, as in *young*. It was a bit of a surprise.

Comment: I suggest replacing the /s with "s to avoid ambiguity with IPA.

Comment: I don't know IPA but it's better to avoid confusion of notation.